# Setting background color of cell

Tags: c#, npoi

To set cell backgound color to RGB = 198, 224, 180 (a green tonality) I am using this:

```
            ICellStyle style = wb.CreateCellStyle();
            var font = (XSSFFont)GetGroupFont(wb);
            style.SetFont(font);

            var backColor = new XSSFColor(new byte[] { 198, 224, 180 });
            style.FillForegroundColor = backColor.Index;
            style.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
            style.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            style.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

            ICell cellGroup = row.CreateCell(0);
            cellGroup.CellStyle = style;
            cellGroup.SetCellValue(value);
```

With the above, the resulting Excel shows a cell with black background. What's wrong?

Comment: does the colour change if you change the values of the byte array? Does it work if you try: `style.FillForegroundColor = HSSFColor.Green.Index`

Comment: @MongZhu it works.... green background with black foreground.

Comment: @MongZhu sorry... it finally worked when I used `((XSSFCellStyle)style).SetFillForegroundColor(backColor);`.... however, I am wondering why one should set `FillForeGroundColor` instead of `FillBackgroundColor`. I tried `FillBackGroundColor` first, but it was still showing the cell with black background.

Comment: unbelievable,... Here is the [crappy example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/de/examples/NPOI.XSSF.UserModel/XSSFColor/-/php-xssfcolor-class-examples.html) that shows what in the end worked in your case, and they use `var`! (this should be forbidden). So you need to cast it explicitly to be able to use this darn method `SetFillForegroundColor`. The Interface does not contain it. Thanx to you man, now I am also a little smarter in the npoi area

Comment: you should write an answer to your question, since you found a solution. This definetely will help people in the future. Because apparently the tutorial examples are not as easy understandable as they are meant to be